# IP address and system details of msg.sender

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

Is it possible to log the IP address and various system details (meta data etc.) about a msg.sender who is sending a transaction to your smart contract?

Comment: Log it where???

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it is possible. At least, it cannot be found in the documentation: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.1/miscellaneous.html#index-4

Moreover, it would be a major paradox into a blockchain (at least a public one). One nice element is that it is very hard to know who is who in a network unless you want people to know it. If you have access to IP address in the smart contract, it could be very helpful knowing who is the owner of a eth address.

Comment: Yeah but often, people interact with a smart contract through some sort of application running a node, i.e. they're not running a node themselves but perhaps use a wallet service. If the wallet service is running the node or let's say someone is using infura, then these 3rd parties could be logging everything no?

Comment: @NowsyMe Correct. But the fact that someone is doing it is not a reason to do it too ^^

Comment: Ok, I'm asking because I read it was a research topic to create a network which anonymise meta data from transactions like this on public chains like ethereum

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Only the node that receive the transaction could know it, but once the transaction is spread to the others nodes, this is hopefully lost.